How to build a relationship in Laravel with an altered column value
this is my first question in StackOverflow. I am here because I am trying to build a particular relationship in Laravel. I would like to be able to make something like THIS
public function game()
{
     $original_game_name = preg_replace('/\s+BONUS.(\s+|\d+)+/', '', $this->game);

     //I would like to use the current table game column modified to match the value at $original_game_name for the relationship. SOmething like: 
     //return $this->hasOne('VanguardLTE\Game', 'name', $orginal_game_name);

     return $this->hasOne('VanguardLTE\Game', 'name', 'game');
} 

I want it to be a relationship so I can eager load this relationship if needed easily usign "with".
I tried putting $orginal_game_name directly in third argument of the hasOne method, and of course that didn't work since it accepts a column name. I thought about using a Query Building but I am kinda lost to what would be the way to use it in this case.

I ended using a leftJoin in my original query. Like:
->leftJoin('games', 'stat_game.game', '=', \DB::raw('REGEX_REPLACE(games.name, "\s+BONUS.(\s+|\d+)+", "")'))

In Laravel, relationships like hasOne, hasMany, etc., are designed to work based on column mappings, not dynamically generated values. Since you're trying to modify the column's value on the fly, a regular relationship won't work directly in this case.
However, You can define a custom relationship using a query builder inside the relationship method. This will allow you to use a dynamically generated value ($original_game_name) to fetch the related data.
public function game()
{
    $original_game_name = preg_replace('/\s+BONUS.(\s+|\d+)+/', '', $this->game);

    return $this->hasOne('VanguardLTE\Game', 'name', 'name')
        ->where('name', $original_game_name);
}




Hi. Thanks a lot for your answer.
I tried that and no luck. I realized that $this->game (or $this->AnyColumn) it's alway null. I did a json_encode($this) and it is an empty array for PHP. So I believe I need to share more info. This is my query.
StatGame::with(['user' => function ($query) { $query->select('id', 'username'); }, 'game' => function($query) { $query->select('id', 'name', 'original_id'); }])->get();
